# Find real domain of a function results in $x \geq i$

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

I have an equation of the form

$$f(x) = \sqrt{x^3 + x}$$

for which one needs to define the maximal domain, and image and domain are part of $\mathbb{R}$ (real numbers).

$$x^3 + x \geq 0 \implies x^2 \geq -1 \implies x \geq i$$

This seems a little confusing to me, since $i$ is an element of $\mathbb{C}$ and not $\mathbb{R}$.

What am I missing?

Can $x \geq i$ be a valid domain of the function given the above constraints?

Comment: An example of a number $\geq i$ is $i$ itself.

Comment: True. But what is smallest number $x > i$?

Comment: $x^3+x = x(x^2+1)$, so $f$ is defined for $x\geq 0$...

Comment: You are doing two things wrong: i) You shouldn't divide by $x$ in your inequality without checking that $x\neq 0$, and for the sign of $x$; ii) Your confusion with the inequality $x\geq i$ is because this is nonsense; is the square-root function defined over negative numbers? What is the square root of $x^2$ again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of $\sqrt{x^3+x}$ is defined for
$$x^3+x=x\times(x^2+1)$$
Since $\forall x,x^2+1>0$, we need $x>0$. I.e., the domain of $f(x)$ is simply
$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\geq0\}$$

Answer (score 3):

For real numbers, $x^2 + 1$ is always positive.  That's not where the problem lies.  The problem is the other factor in  $x^3 + x = x (x^2 + 1)$.

Comment: Thank you. But if $x^2 + 1 > 0$ (is always positive) this is equivalent to saying $x^2 > -1$, which is not part of the real numbers anymore. What do you mean with "the problem is the other factor"?

Comment: @mwhs By "the problem is the other factor", he means $x$ can be negative, and that's where $f(x)$ is not defined.

Comment: "this is equivalent to saying $x^2>−1$, which is not part of the real numbers anymore"; this is wrong, wrong, wrong

Comment: @mwhs Really? That's the part of your sentence that you're questioning?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn What part were you talking about when you said "wrong"?

Comment: @mwhs $x^2>-1$ does NOT imply that $x>i$. So since $1^2>-1$, is $1>i$? Consider the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$.